# assign agrv[i] from lines in file using python

Tags: python, configparser

example input.dat

```
[settings]
port = 1234
host = abc.com
```

How can I parse the file, and assign 
`1234 to agrv[1]`, 
`abc.com to argv[2]` and so on

here is what i tried:

```
$python p.py input.dat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 8, in <module>
    print config['settings']['host']
AttributeError: ConfigParser instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

p.py

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys
    import ConfigParser

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(sys.argv[1])
        print config['settings']['host']
        print config['settings']['port']
```

I don't want to use python3 if I can help it.

Comment: Note: If you weren't opposed to Python 3, as of Python 3.2, `configparser` [would support the exact approach you're trying to use](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigParser does not support dict-like lookup. After parsing the file, you retrieve values using its get() method, which takes two arguments, the names of the section and option. So:

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(sys.argv[1])
print config.get('settings', 'host')
print config.get('settings', 'port')
```

More info here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#configparser-objects

Comment: Note: On Python 3.2+, [`dict`-like lookup is supported](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access). If you're writing new code, there is very little reason to avoid moving to Python 3.

Comment: @johndburger so can I do something like $cat test.txt | python p.py , so I don't have to type the arguments, but take them from test.txt

Comment: @kamal That's a separate issue, but yes, you can do that. If you want to allow for either reading the config from stdin _or_ taking it from the command line, I recommend the file inputs module. This would let you write something like this:

`config.readfp(fileinput.input())`

(Note the switch to the readfp() method.) And then you can write either of these on the command line:

`$ cat test.txt | python p.py`
or
`$ python p.py test.txt`

More about fileinput here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html